# Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: web-services, visual-studio, debugging

I've one solution with 2 project: a web service and a project that consume him. With my Visual Studio 2008 Professional I can debug both projects (start with the project and when I call the web service I can debug the code), but no with Visual Studio Express 2010. 
Is this a limitation of the "Express" version of my IDE?!?

Thank for your attention.

Comment: Yes, this is a limitation of the *Express* version: Web service projects are only supported in "Web Developer Express" version.

Comment: Is not the solution!!!! Have other ideas?!?

Comment: @Filburt: thank you very much.  I thought so! Otherwise why microsoft sells professional editions? :D

Comment: The only possible workaround would be to run both: C# Express and Web Developer Express and make the Web Service Reference in your C# project point to the port the Web Service is running under in Web Developer Express. If this will allow seemless debugging I cannot tell.